# How do I access the root of my Laravel with just "/" on the route

Tags: laravel

I'm running my installed Laravel via the command line with the command below:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

However, I need to add a path to the "/" on the route (\routes\web.php)

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});
```

Is there a way to access the root by just having "/" ?

Comment: `Route::get('/', ...);` ?

Comment: @tkausl Now it's working. Earlier on, I was getting an error :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use it like this:

```
Route::get('/', 'YourController@method');

// Or simply load a blade template without using a controller
Route::view('/', 'some-template.blade.php');
```

Checkout the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing for more about Routing.

Comment: As long as `public function method()` in `YourController.php` has `return view('some-template')`, that 2nd `Route::view()` method is not required.

Comment: @vanderbake After I relaunched the webserver, I'm getting the error "The site cannot be reached".

Comment: @JunDolor this could be a webserver issue. Are you on Mac or Windows? And what happens if you use eg. `Route::get('/', function() { dump('Hello world'); });` at the top of your routes/web.php below the <?php (and remove the rest).

Comment: @vanderbake It's now working. Thanks so much for helping me out here. Much obliged :-)